# Assign Unique Values according Distinct Columns Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I know the question name is a little ambiguous.

My goal is to assign global key column based on 2 columns + unique value in my data frame.

For example

```
CountryCode | Accident
   AFG          Car
   AFG          Bike
   AFG          Car
   AFG          Plane
   USA          Car
   USA          Bike
   UK           Car
```

Let Car = 01, Bike = 02, Plane = 03

My desire global key format is [Accident][CountryCode][UniqueValue]

Unique value is a count of similar [Accident][CountryCode]

so if Accident = Car and CountryCode = AFG and it is the first occurrence, the global key would be 01AFG01

The desired dataframe would look like this:

```
CountryCode | Accident | GlobalKey
   AFG          Car        01AFG01
   AFG          Bike       02AFG01
   AFG          Car        01AFG02
   AFG          Plane      01AFG03
   USA          Car        01USA01
   USA          Bike       01USA02
   UK           Car        01UK01
```

I have tried running a for loop to append Accident Number and CountryCode together

for example:

```
globalKey = []

for x in range(0,6):
    string = df.iloc[x, 1]
    string2 = df.iloc[x, 2]
    if string2 == 'Car':
        number = '01'
    elif string2 == 'Bike':
        number = '02'
    elif string2 == 'Plane':
        number = '03'
    #Concat the number of accident and Country Code
    subKey = number + string
    #Append to the list
    globalKey.append(subKey)
```

This code will provide me with something like `01AFG`, `02AFG` based on the value I assign. but I want to assign a unique value by counting the occurrence of when `CountryCode` and `Accident` is similar.

I am stuck with the code above. I think there should be a better way to do it using map function in Pandas.

Thanks for helping guys!
much appreciate!

Comment: Shouldn't the `AFG Plane` row have a `Global key` of `03AFG01`??

Comment: and the `USA Bike` be `02USA01`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with `cumcount` to achieve this in a number of steps, like this:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['AFG','AFG','AFG','AFG','USA','USA','UK'], 'Accident':['Car','Bike','Car','Plane','Car','Bike','Car']})

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
  Accident Country
0      Car     AFG
1     Bike     AFG
2      Car     AFG
3    Plane     AFG
4      Car     USA
5     Bike     USA
6      Car      UK

## Create a column to keep incremental values for `Country`
In [3]: df['cumcount'] = df.groupby('Country').cumcount()

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
  Accident Country  cumcount
0      Car     AFG         0
1     Bike     AFG         1
2      Car     AFG         2
3    Plane     AFG         3
4      Car     USA         0
5     Bike     USA         1
6      Car      UK         0

## Create a column to keep incremental values for combination of `Country`,`Accident`
In [5]: df['cumcount_type'] = df.groupby(['Country','Accident']).cumcount()

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
  Accident Country  cumcount  cumcount_type
0      Car     AFG         0              0
1     Bike     AFG         1              0
2      Car     AFG         2              1
3    Plane     AFG         3              0
4      Car     USA         0              0
5     Bike     USA         1              0
6      Car      UK         0              0
```

And from that point on you can concatenate the values of `cumcount`, `cumcount_type` and `Country` to achieve what you're after.

Maybe you want to add `1` to each of the values you have under the different counts, depending on whether you want to start counting from 0 or 1.

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is not exactly what OP needs but maybe he can get an idea from it.

Comment: You are right @Ev.Kounis , I will fix as soon as the OP clarifies the inconsistency in their description. I think the problem becomes trivial from this point on though, but a precise answer is always better :)

Comment: I did expand through this code right here and got it all working. Thank you, Thanos.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use for loops if you can help it. For example, you can do your Accident to code mapping with:

```
df['AccidentCode'] = df['Accident'].map({'Car': '01', 'Bike': '02', 'Plane': '03'})
```

To get the unique code, [Thanos has shown how to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39589991/12663) that using [GroupBy.cumcount](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['CA_ID'] = df.groupby(['CountryCode', 'Accident']).cumcount() + 1
```

And then to put them all together into a unique key:

```
df['NewKey'] = df['AccidentCode'] + df['CountryCode'] + df['CA_ID'].map('{:0>2}'.format)
```

which gives:

```
  CountryCode Accident GlobalKey AccidentCode  CA_ID   NewKey
0         AFG      Car   01AFG01           01      1  01AFG01
1         AFG     Bike   02AFG01           02      1  02AFG01
2         AFG      Car   01AFG02           01      2  01AFG02
3         AFG    Plane   01AFG03           03      1  03AFG01
4         USA      Car   01USA01           01      1  01USA01
5         USA     Bike   01USA02           02      1  02USA01
6          UK      Car    01UK01           01      1   01UK01
```

Comment: This is a much shorter version, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

After you create your `subKey` we can sort the dataframe and count the occurences of the couples. First let's reset the index (to store the original order)

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

then sort by the `subKey` and count

```
df = df.sort_values(by='subKey')
df['newnumber'] = 1

for ind in range(1, len(df)): #start by 1 because first row is always 1
    if df.loc[ind, 'subKey'] == df.loc[ind - 1, 'subKey']:
        df.loc[ind, 'newnumber'] = df.loc[ind - 1, 'newnumber'] + 1
```

Finally create the `GlobalKey` with the help of the `zfill` function, the reorder by `index`:

```
df['GlobalKey'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['subKey'] + str(x['new_number']).zfill(2), 1)
df = df.sort_values(by='index').drop('index', 1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience of Pandas so this answer may not be what you are looking for. That being said, if the data you have is really that simple (few countries, few accident types) have you considered storing each country|accident combination in their own value?

So as you traverse your input, just increment the counter for that country|accident combination, and then read through those counters at the end to produce the `GlobalKeys`.

If you have other data to store besides the Global Key, then store the country|accident combinations as lists, and read through them at the end one-at-a-time to produce `GlobalKeys`.